# phpmyadmin can't connect to mariadb with docker-compose: Packets out of order

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, mariadb

So whats wrong with this docker-compose.yml? It actually looks ok to me.

But when i try to log in to phpmyadmin on http://localhost:8080/index.php
i get errors:

> Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=71
>   mysqli_real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away
>   mysqli_real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=33
>   mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    volumes:
      - test_db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
        - dbtest

  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
    networks:
        - dbtest

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    networks:
      - dbtest

volumes:
  test_db_data:
networks:
  dbtest:
```

Context:

- Docker version 19.03.3
- docker-compose version 1.23.2

**Update:**
I added adminer as well and login also fails.
Mysql stderr shows:

> [Warning] Aborted connection 9 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '192.168.32.3' (This connection closed normally without authentication)

Comment: the compose file seems fine, can try to check mysql logs, also try with `docker-compose down -v && docker-compose rm -f && docker-compose up`, note it clear volume as well.

Comment: i updated question, error in logs is: [Warning] Aborted connection 9 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '192.168.32.3' (This connection closed normally without authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and fixed it by deleting the database volume and recreating the database. Not the nicest of solutions. The MySQL server was getting stuck on startup.

I had the luck of it being a database on a dev box so running migrations and reseeding with test data was all I had to do.